# Attach Dojo Datepicker to an element

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, xpages

Simple question: I have an element with an ID. I want to attach the Dojo Datepicker control after page load to that element. When I click on that element the datepicker should appear. The API documentation lacks with that kind of approach. Did I miss something? Do you have a solution? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

To be clear: I don't want to attach the Datepicker to an input element but to a span/div element (text only). When I click on that element the datepicker should appear. The rest of coding should be done within the datepicker's JS code (change view etc.).
I could use the jQuery Datepicker but I want to achieve a clear and unique user experience. That's why I am asking for the Dojo way ;-)

Comment: is the dijit/DateTextBox not what you need?

Comment: If you are talking about the dojox.mobile.datepicker it does not attach to an element

Comment: No I mean the normal Dojo Datepicker control that should be attached to an element (not an input element but a span/div)

Answer (score 1):

if the dojox.mobile picker is what your looking for, you need to attach it to an overlay.  There is no direct attachment. like the dijit/datetextbox.  If the mobile picker is what you want below is an example.

When using the opener, inside the show() is where you tell it what to attach to.

```
<div id="customPicker" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Opener" data-dojo-props="onHide:setDeliveryDate">
     <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" label="Custom Picker">
              <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" label="Done" class="mblColorBlue" style="width:45px;float:right;" onClick="dijit.registry.byId('customPicker').hide()"></div>
      </h1>
    <div id="dateSpinner" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/DatePicker" data-dojo-props="monthPattern:'MM', dayPattern:'dd'"></div>
</div>

<input id="dateField" onclick="dijit.registry.byId('customPicker').show(this)"></input>
```

and the Script::

```
require(["dojo","dojox/mobile/Opener","dojox/mobile/Heading", "dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton","dojox/mobile/DatePicker", "dijit/registry"])


    function setDeliveryDate(){

        var spin =dijit.registry.byId("dateSpinner");
        dojo.byId("dateField").value = spin.slots[1].value + "/" + spin.slots[2].value + "/" + spin.slots[0].value;


    }
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/PrJzp/

EDIT::

To have a calendar in a span use the dijit/Calendar component.

```
require([
    "dijit/Calendar",
    "dojo/date",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Calendar, date){
    new Calendar({
        value: new Date(),
    }, "SpanWhereCalendarIS");
});
```

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Calendar.html

Comment: Nope, I don't wanna attach it to an input element but to a span/div element.

Comment: Ok that is easier::                                                         var dp = new dojox.mobile DatePicker({id:"DPId1", monthPattern:"MM", dayPattern:"dd"});
dojo.byId("SpanID").appendChild(dp.domNode);
dp.startup();

Comment: I dont wanna use the mobile control, just the normal Datepicker control attached to a span element when I click it

Comment: I would use the dijit/Calendar then, it just creates a calendar widget.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your XPage loads Dojo and then set dojoType to dijit.form.DateTextBox on your inputText control.

You can also set dojoType on the XPages date picker control. Paul Withers have a blog post on this: http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-date-picker-my-preference/

Comment: And again: i have no input element, just a span/div element that is clickable. Cannot believe that this should not be possible like in jQuery. There you can attach every widget on every element you want.